# Fix RepeatedResourceWarning for Helm Chart deployed by ArgoCD

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argocd

I have ArgoCD deployed into a K8S cluster which deploys multiple applications based ony Helm charts into my cluster. Each application is stored within a dedicated Git repo and uses a Chart.yaml file to specify a dependency (e.g. the ArgoCD helm chart). In addition I want to customise this Helm chart by overwriting certain K8S resources (e.g. config maps) by defining the corresponding file within a templates directory inside the same repo where the Chart.yaml is stored. I know that I could use the values.yaml file to make these changes, however I would like to have the file within the templates folder. After syncing the application to my cluster I receive a "RepeatedResourceWarning" message.

How can I tell ArgoCD to prioritise always the configuration within the templates folder?

[image: ArgoCD Screenshot]

[image: Chart.yaml file within the repository]

[image: Overwrites within the templates folder]

Comment: This is a limitation of Helm. You cannot overwrite resources that are defined already in dependent charts. You can either fork the Helm Chart you want to edit, or use another tool such as Kustomize which fits this usecase better